# array help. How to multiply arrays by itself, without the first element in one, and without the last element in the other

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, dom

my array from user input: [1,2,3,4]

what I want:

[1,2,3]*[2,3,4]
(1*2) + (2*3) + (3*4) = 20

what I have so far:

```
var array = [];
var number= document.getElementById("number").value; //this is where user inputs the number for my array

var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i< number.length; i++){
    array.push(parseInt(number[i]));
    var first= number[i-1];
    var second = number[i+1];
    sum += (first*second);
}
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for an array for this.

In the following pattern: (1*2) + (2*3) + (3*4) you can see how this can occur using for loop without array.

Following works:

```
var number= parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value); //this is where user inputs the number for my array
var sum=0;
for (var i = 1; i< number; i++){
    sum += i*(i+1);
}
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: if I do this i get NaN.  Should i still be able to use parseInt()?

Comment: I am getting 0 for some reason.

Comment: Your are getting 0 for sum or number?

Comment: on my console sum is 0

Comment: That means number is 0. Try setting number manually to something. Then your problem is that number is not being populated as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

that is my solution with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method of array

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((a, c, i, s) => (s[i + 1] ? c * s[i + 1] + a : a), 0);
```

Comment: Your solution assumes array is populated. No need for array for this problem. See my above answer.

Comment: @Maxqueue i saw you answer. he sad "input is array".  You calculating array indexes and not array items. try to shuffle that array and see if you get correct output.  BTW i don't understand why you converting array to number. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You could use slice to get subsets of the arrays and then use reduce to create the sum like this:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4]

const first = arr.slice(0, -1)
const last = arr.slice(1, arr.length)

const result = first.reduce((acc, num, idx) => acc + num * last[idx], 0)

console.log(result)
```